# Counting the number of times a edge is visited in Minimum Spanning tree for all paths from vertex u to v where u!=v

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given a MST find for all paths starting from **u** ending at **v** where u!=v, the number of times each edge in the graph is traversed.
*For example edge AC in the graph can be traversed while reaching from A to C or from A to B where C may lie in the path from A to B. Hence AC is traversed twice.*
We need to count all traversals for each edge in the graph.
Can anyone help me with the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a minimum spanning tree **M** = {**V**,**E**} and an edge `(i,j)`, let **L** = {**V**<sub>L</sub>, **E**<sub>L</sub>} and **R** = {**V**<sub>R</sub>, **E**<sub>R</sub>} be the two subgraphs (trees) created by deleting edge `(i,j)` from **M**. Edge `(i,j)` will only be crossed by paths `(u,v)` where `u` is in **L** and `v` is in **R** (or vice-versa). Since all vertices in **L** are connected to all vertices in **R**, and all paths from vertex `u` to vertex `v` are unique, the number of times edge `(i,j)` is crossed is |**V**<sub>L</sub>|×|**V**<sub>R</sub>|.

To find the number of vertices on one side of each edge, all that's required is a single depth-first traversal starting at a an arbitrary node, returning a `nodeCount` that is the sum of the `nodeCount` for each child + 1 for the current node. The `nodeCount` for leaf nodes is therefore 1.

The parent vertex is removed from the adjacency list passed in the recursive calls to its children so that the nodes are not counted multiple times.

So if we reached vertex **p** from vertex **R** as shown in this subgraph,

```
        R
        |
        |
        p
       / \
      /   \
     c1   c2
```

the `nodeCount` returned to **R** will be `1 + nodeCount(c1) + nodeCount(c2)`. If both **c1** and **c2** are leaf nodes, the `nodeCount` returned will be 3.

At the end of this process, each of the `nodeCount` values returned will be the number of nodes on *one* side of the corresponding edge. The number of nodes on the other side of that edge will be given by `N - nodeCount`, where `N` is the number of vertices in the MST. The number of paths through that edge would be

```
nodeCount * (N - nodeCount)
```

Here's some pseudocode that will hopefully clarify things a bit:

```
CountNodes(A, r)
   // Given adjacency matrix A, returns the number of nodes 
   // reachable from node r (including r itself)
   nodeCount = 1   // include root node in count

   // rows/columns in A for visited nodes should be all 0
   // so that we don't count this node multiple times
   // update node r as visited before recursive call to CountNodes
   A[r,] = 0
   A[,r] = 0

   if the number of unvisited children of r is 0
      return nodeCount   // r is a leaf, nodeCount = 1
   end if

   for each  node c connected to r
      // get count of nodes in subtree rooted at c
      childCount = CountNodes(A, c)
      PRINT (r,c) = childCount   // display count for current edge 
      nodeCount = nodeCount + childCount   // update count to report to parent
   end for
   return nodeCount

end CountNodes
```

As I said, for the initial call we use an arbitrary node. It doesn't matter which one we use, as all answers will be equivalent (the proper count from *one* side of each edge, though not necessarily the *same* side). The initial call implicitly generates a dummy vertex as the parent of the first node, so the `nodeCount` returned at the end is equal to **N**, the number of vertices in the MST.

Here's a sample adjacency matrix for 10 vertices and output from the function when starting from vertex 0:

```
A =
   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
   0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0

(6,3) = 1
(8,2) = 1
(5,9) = 1
(8,5) = 2
(6,8) = 4
(7,6) = 6
(4,7) = 7
(1,4) = 8
(0,1) = 9
return =  10
```

Since the `nodeCount` for edge `(6,8)` is `4`, the number of paths passing through edge `(6,8)` is `4 * (10 - 4) = 24`. The number of paths through edge `(0,1)` will be `9`

Comment: Sorry I just asked the algorithm, but can you help me with the data structure and implementation? I have been stuck on this since yesterday!

Comment: I thought of doing it as follow: for each edge apply DFS on both the vertices  ignoring the other vertex of the edge during the DFS to count the number of nodes connected to that vertex. But that would be many DFS searches. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: I tried this but had a doubt regarding counting the child nodes. When I am doing the DFS, let's say first node has single neighbour, this node therefore has one child node. Moving onto the child node let's say it has in all 3 adjacent neighbours, so how many child nodes does this node have, 2 or 3?

Comment: And N * ( N - nodeCount), where N is number of vertices in MST and nodeCount is the nodeCount of which vertex of the current edge? Because it will be different for the both vertices for the current edge. If not please explain a little.

Comment: I finally got a chance to sit down and look at this and I was overthinking the problem. All that's needed is a depth-first traversal of the original tree. I'll write up some info on the algorithm.

Comment: Thank a lot for your time. Brilliant solution.